# WebDriverException: Remote-webdriver with selenium grid in setup method in conftest.py

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying run my tests in Selenium Grid 4.2.1. I created hub and node with Google Chrome. My setup method is in conftest file in 'tests' folder. I used fixture in setup method and when I run my tests, the output is:

test setup failed

request = SubRequest 'setup' for Function test_properly_loggining_url

**WebDriverException**: Message: Unable to find handler for (POST) /session.

```
import pytest as pytest
import webdriver_manager.chrome
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


conftest.py
@pytest.fixture()
def setup(request):
    grid_url = "http://192.168.88.189:5555"
    driver = webdriver.Remote(grid_url, DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield
    driver.stop_client()
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

test_file.py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class TestLogin:

    def test_properly_loggining_url(self):
        Login = HomePage(self.driver)
        Login.properly_loggining()
        assert Login.get_current_url() == Login.home_page
```

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?